# Deleting a row from a dynamic HTML table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I want To delete a row by making an json request, but unfortunately the code is not working.

```
function deleteRecord(id) {
    debugger;
    // === Show confirmation alert to user before delete a record.
    var ans = confirm("Are you sure to delete a record?");

    // === If user pressed Ok then delete the record else do nothing.
    if (ans == true) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: location.pathname + "WebForm5.aspx/deleteRecord",
            data: id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            async: "true",
            success: function (dt) {
                debugger;

                //=== rebind data to remove delete record from the table.
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                $(".errMsg ul").remove();
                $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Record successfully delete.</li></ul>");
                $(".errMsg").show("slow");
                clear();
            },
            error: function (dt) {
                alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my code cehind aspx.cs code in ASP.net:

```
public static void deleteRecord(int CategoryID)
{
    clsCategoryBL objproject = new clsCategoryBL();
    objproject.CategoryDelete(CategoryID);
}
```

I want to solve the problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to tell where exactly your code isnt working. is it geting answer from serverside? is it only doesnt delete row or what? what is not working?

Comment: In the serverside it is not working..You just explain me details in answer so that i can understand..

Comment: i think the problem is in the jquery code..  HERE THE ERROR data: id,SHOW THAT IT WILL DIRECTLY CALLING THE  error: function (dt) {
                alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
            }

Comment: Soo you dont get answer from serverside? is the serverside script in same directory as file that contains javascript?

Comment: jes i know its library but language is javascript

Comment: YES SIR,Output provides me error error: function (dt) { alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText); }...The problem is on id declaration so that it will automatically call the error function

Comment: soo serverside file - WebForm5.aspx is in the same folder as the file where is `deleteRecord()` function?

Comment: yea...at the same file...so the error comes from this debugger  $.ajax({

Comment: try change `url: location.pathname + "WebForm5.aspx/deleteRecord"` to `url: "WebForm5.aspx/deleteRecord"` because you dont need that pathname if files is in one folder

Comment: no the same problem...you just guide me how to solve this

Comment: error: is called when return statuss is not OK soo problem may be in path to .aspx file or in that file

Comment: try to change aspx file soo that it returns something, then you can see what it returns in console

Comment: The id is coming but where is the problem?

Comment: if id is comming to .aspx file and jquery throws error: then problem is in your .aspx file - maybe there is problems with class instance declaration. i dont know how you add that class, what it does and maybe that error is thrown by that class when you call method. but i dont know .aspx i know a little php soo cant help there.

Answer (score 0):

add custom id atributes to rows (tr) when you create list like

```
<tr data-id='1'></tr>
<tr data-id='2'></tr>
```

then you can change line

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

TO

```
$('tr[data-id='+id+']').remove();
```